# cmd does not support unc paths as current directories pushd

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

i was trying to copy a files modified today from one shared drive another shared drive.
but when i execute the batch file, it displays the following error.

cmd does not support unc paths as current directories

the script is as below

```
@echo off


Set PhotosrcPath=\\hqcp-appsvr01\Files\ApplicationDocuments\AppDocs\49\PHOTO\
Set PhotodestPath=\\hqcp-appsvr02\Files\ApplicationDocuments\AppDocs\49\PHOTO\

::Copy photoFiles from server1 to server2 Made Or Modified Today


@echo off

set source=%d%%PhotosrcPath%
set dest=%d%%PhotodestPath%


pushd "%source%"
set t=%date:~4%
echo %t%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d') do call :PROCESS "%%a"
goto :eof
popd

:PROCESS
for /f %%j in ('echo %~t1') do set d=%%j
if "%d%"=="%t%" Xcopy /y %1 "%dest%"
goto :eof
```

Comment: Yeah - I can only offer a workaround - you need to map your src and dest paths to drive letters, then use those drive letter instead.

Comment: how do you do that mapping?

Comment: but i am new to these scripts, can you help me in mapping the src and dest path to the drive letters?

Comment: You just can't change current directory to a UNC path. CMD is happy to do so but MS knows it breaks other programs. Therefore don'tchange the current directory, you don't need to, so don't. You can force CMD to use UNC paths by starting it with the current dir to a UNC path andsetting this dword to 1 (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor) DisableUNCChecks

Comment: i have mapped the directories now and it is working fine.now the cmd prompt window is not closing automatically.how can i close the window automatically after excuting the script.

Comment: @Noodles, **Doesn't work.** Where did you get that info from?

Answer (score 4):

```
net use X: \\hqcp-appsvr01\Files\ApplicationDocuments\AppDocs\49\PHOTO
net use Y: \\hqcp-appsvr02\Files\ApplicationDocuments\AppDocs\49\PHOTO

::Copy photoFiles from server1 to server2 Made Or Modified Today

@echo off

set source=X:\
set dest=Y:\

pushd "%source%"
set t=%date:~4%
echo %t%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d') do call :PROCESS "%%a"
popd
net use Y: /d /y
net use X: /d /y
goto :eof

:PROCESS
for /f %%j in ('echo %~t1') do set d=%%j
if "%d%"=="%t%" Xcopy /y %1 "%dest%"
goto :eof
```

Something like that might work. Look up NET USE for more information.

I'm curious why you aren't just using XCOPY - I would think that the /D command might do what you need. I would throw in a /M too.

```
xcopy \\hqcp-appsvr01\Files\ApplicationDocuments\AppDocs\49\PHOTO\*.* \\hqcp-appsvr02\Files\ApplicationDocuments\AppDocs\49\PHOTO\*.*  /y /d /m
```

Comment: But the [Microsoft documentation for pushd](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/pushd.mspx?mfr=true&tduid=(df0dead6460f26ca30517cce6f76eb9e)(266696)(1503186)(skim725X6551X1fa61b02269089e3b3870af3e7622078)()) says that "If you specify a network path, the pushd command temporarily assigns the first unused drive letter (starting with Z:) to the specified network resource". So aren't your `net use` statements unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use pushd. The following modification of the for loop may be enough.

```
for /f %%a in ('dir "%source%" /b /a-d /o-d') do call :PROCESS "%%a"
```

Comment: This is correct - xcopy supports network paths - I wasn't even thinking about that.